# Part of the scene disappearing

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Hope you are doing great.

I am coming across a difficulty with the adding up of layers on VSE.
As you can see on the following video, https://youtu.be/Eopt36z7HH8

Part of the animated characters and part of the ground disappear at some point, which is of course undesirable.
The characters come from Muvizu imported as layer 1 on Blender VSE.
The FPS seems fine most of the time on Blender. I tried several times to reimported the characters as layers but I always get the same disappearing. I see no issue on the Muvizu side, I do not see any on Blender so I just cannot tell where the issue come from?

The only thing I can indicate is that usually Muvizu is 25 Fps that I have to increase to match the rest of the content on Blender but I do not know is this can have an impact of this "disappearing"

Any idea that could help?

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: I think I uploaded it on Blend exchange. First time I am doing this so hopefully you can get it!
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=rg4kOw88" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/rg4kOw88/)

Comment: yes, that worked but....i cannot see anything because you did not include your png/mov files. so please before upload the file again, go to file -> external data -> pack all into blend. then upload again. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Chris...I read your message and understood it.  just discovered what is going on...The issue does not come from Blender but from Muvizu...When I make (export) the video as image sequence on Muvizu, the PNGs are damaged and part of them are missing. So when you run the image sequence as animation on Blender some parts are disappearing. The issue comes from Muvizu so no use to burden Blender guys on an issue that is not relevant to Blender...Muvizu team should resolve this. I will close my post once you will have seen my reply. Thanks for you intention to help and your attention Chris.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your info. You are welcome!